# Adding Components To JFrame in separate Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

I am writing a wizard of sorts and would like to switch what is displayed using methods. Every time I run this code I get a null pointer exception.

```
    public class EventDispatch {

       public static void main(String [] args){
            WizardScreen wiz = new WizardScreen();
            new Thread(wiz).start();
            wiz.welcomeScreen();
       }
    }

    public class WizardScreen implements Runnable{

protected JFrame wizardFrame;
protected JPanel contentPane;
protected JButton newQuote; 
protected JButton openQuote;
protected JLabel title;
GridBagConstraints c;


public WizardScreen(){
    wizardFrame = new JFrame();
    contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    wizardFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    wizardFrame.setSize(550, 450);
    wizardFrame.setResizable(false);
    wizardFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    wizardFrame.setTitle("Welcome!");
    wizardFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    wizardFrame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running wizardScreen");

}

public void welcomeScreen(){
    title = new JLabel("Welcome to ExSoft Quote Calculator Alpha 1.0");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = .5;
    contentPane.add(title, c);
    wizardFrame.validate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the full exception stack trace, and tell us which line in your code it is referring to. This is important in trying to determine the cause of your NullPointerException

Comment: *"Adding Components To JFrame in seperate Thread"* - My first thought is, don't.  Swing is not thread safe.  All modifications or interactions to the UI should be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a walk through your code...

First, you create an instance of `WizardScreen` this initialises

- `wizardFrame`
- `contentPane`

Second, you start a `Thread`...

Third, you call `welcomeScreen` on the instance of `WizardScreen`, this initialises...

- `title`

It then tries to access the `gridx` property of `c`...which hasn't yet been initialised...

You should have checked the information that the `NullPointerException` was giving you...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at eventdispatch.EventDispatch$WizardScreen.welcomeScreen(EventDispatch.java:52)
    at eventdispatch.EventDispatch.main(EventDispatch.java:20)
```

It clear states where the exception occurred, this is invaluable information both to you and us.

Beware, Swing is not thread safe, all interactions and modifications to the UI are expected to occur from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

FYI:

It's generally advisable to use `pack` of `setSize`, which should be done last, right before you call `setVisible`.  Also beware, that using `setResizable(false)` changes the size of the window...

```
wizardFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//wizardFrame.setSize(550, 450);
//wizardFrame.setResizable(false);
//wizardFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
wizardFrame.setTitle("Welcome!");
wizardFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
wizardFrame.setResizable(false);
wizardFrame.pack();
wizardFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
wizardFrame.setVisible(true);
```